# Start/max duration of my audio is not showing on slider

Tags: flutter, slider, provider

I'm new to flutter. I'm using audioplayers.

I want the max duration of my audio on the right, and the position of the audio on the left.
First, I tried tried without provider and it works, [Inistate code without provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pafke.png), but as soon as I close the alertDialog, I got this error [Inistate code without provider error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prsHv.jpg). I know that if I use the dispose method it will work, but I need the audio playing outside of the alertDialog.

So then I tried with the provider : [Initstate code with provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgWVi.png),  [AudioProvider for duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUafo.png) and [Slider code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uznhc.png).
Now the thing that I do not understand, is why when I print the value of the position,it is good [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf9Ki.png), but it is not displayed in the Slider
[Slider on the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgVcX.jpg)

Comment: I don't really understand... Why don't you use if(mounted) ? Provider is meant for comminicate between widget. It's recommanded to use setState as much as possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.